# android : detect the reinstall of an app from the app code

Tags: android, broadcast, reinstall

Is there a way to detect from app code when it is being reinstalled.

I saw that app update from market can be detected by listening to PACKAGE_REPLACED event in broadcast receiver. But that these events are not delivered to the app , if the app is reinstalled from editor (eclipse ).

My requirement is that i am disabling a component(Launcher activity). The app install will fail if it is not enabled. SO everytime before reinstall i want to enable this component.

I am talking about the reinstall before publishing in market. While developing , each time i reinstall the app to test some modification, i want to detect this from my app and make the component enabled.

Comment: does installation of exactly same file count as reinstall?

Comment: can you please be more explicit ? i dint get your question

Comment: if I install exactly same .apk file, which contains exactly same contents, do you consider this as reinstall or not?

Comment: For me it could be the same apk or a modified one. I have edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw from my example that the following events will be broadcasted when an app is reinstalled from eclipse.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
             </intent-filter>
```

I defined a broadcast receiver for these actions and from onreceive i am able to enable my component