# How to know an Android app has been downloaded before

Tags: android, google-play, installation, apk

I got the requirement to detect if the app has been downloaded before. The app is a paid app, right now it uses a flag in the SharedPreference to check if that is the first run, if yes it gives some free credits. Some users just uninstall and re-install again to get free credits. Is there a way to detect if the app has been downloaded from the play store before? I looked at the Google Play API but did not find what I wanted. Is there a way to do that without setting up our own server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [android : detect the reinstall of an app from the app code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10410476/android-detect-the-reinstall-of-an-app-from-the-app-code)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above linked question. Whatever you do, you can not reliable detect re-installs locally on user device. End user can factory reset and then re-install the app or they can install the app on a different device. I am not sure, but you should probably consider give free credits as an in-app purchases. Maybe there is an API to determine if that's the first purchase or not...

Comment: The link added on top has nothing to do with the question asked.